# FreeSwitch IP PBX server

Tags: ip, asterisk, telephony, freeswitch

I am doing a project related to IP telephony. I want to use an IP/PBX server in this project. I know about Asterisk and had some experience of it. But I heard about FreeSwitch which is somehow light in terms of resource consumption. Can I use it as IP/PBX server or only I have to go through Asterisk.Kindly shed some light into it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

FreeSWITCH is almost a full replacement for Asterisk. Asterisk has a bit wider hardware support, simply because it's an older project. But if you're working with SIP trunks and no voice hardware, FreeSWITCH is the right way to go. I would recommend it for any new project.

The best way to learn it is to read [the book](http://www.packtpub.com/freeswitch-1-0-6-build-robust-high-performance-telephony-systems/book). It will take you a couple of days, but then you will be able to build a new system on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I work at 2600hz, the company where Darren (one of the three authors of the linked book in the other reply) is CEO. FreeSWITCH is awesome and extremely powerful.

We use FreeSWITCH as the media server in our full stack Telecom Solution: Kazoo. It's open-source, forkable, and available as SaaS from us if you don't want to get your hands dirty. It has APIs for all the call control functionality you want and can be integrated into whatever app you want using your favorite scripting language :).

Check out our main site here: http://2600hz.com

Check out our Kazoo Hosted here: http://kazoo.io

Check out our wiki here: http://wiki.2600hz.com

Check out our GitHub repo here: https://github.com/2600hz/kazoo

Cheers,
Joshua

Disclaimer: I'm the community manager for 2600hz.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , freeswitch will really helpfull to you .

just read the books and you will able to configure it.

i configured my freeswitch PBX/server, and its working fine now.

its support scripting languages that help you for automation.